# Get daily average CPU usage from Digital Ocean graphs

Tags: performance, graph, load, digital-ocean, cpu-usage

How can one get daily average CPU usage, so check if a specific optimization affected overall daily CPU usage?
I mean if there is any API or tool to get this average?
Check my sketch for example of daily average, in red color

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No you can't - there is an open issue to allow reading this data but hasn't been implemented yet

If you need this data - I think Vultr and Linode apis provide it [this assumes you can move cloud providers]